# My "If Else statement" is not working in JavaScript (attempting to perform an equation and if the values are false, alert the user)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Problem:
I am attempting to create an If Else statement, that when the user enters an incorrect value, outside of the range 0 to 80, it alerts the user to input a correct number.
It performs the equation the way I want it to, but when I purposefully input incorrect values, an alert does not appear and the program continues to answer the equation as if nothing ever happened.

The Code:

```js
'use strict';

function calculate() {

  var regPay;
  var regHours = document.getElementById('regHours').value;
  var hourlyRate = document.getElementById('hourlyRate').value;

  if (regHours > 0 || regHours < 80) {
    regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
    document.getElementById('regPay').value = regPay;
    regPay = regPay.toFixed(2);
  } else if (regHours < 0 || regHours > 80) {
    alert("Enter valid number");
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
label {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  display     : inline-block;
  width       : 10em;
  }
div {
  margin : .2em;
  }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payroll Calculator, find out how much you make!</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="regHours">Hours Worked (Between 0 and 80)</label>
      <input type="text" name="regHours" id="regHours" value="0" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="hourlyRate">Hourly Rate</label>
      <input type="text" name="hourlyRate" id="hourlyRate" value="0.00" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="regPay">Regular Pay</label>
      <input type="text" name="regPay" id="regPay" value="0.00">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `regHours = document.getElementById('regHours').value` is a string, you need to parse it to the number type of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way

```
function calculate() {
    'use strict';
    var regPay;
    var regHours = document.getElementById('regHours').value; 
    var hourlyRate = document.getElementById('hourlyRate').value;

    if (regHours > 0 || regHours < 80) {
      regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
      document.getElementById('regPay').value = regPay;
      regPay = regPay.toFixed(2);
      return true
  } 
   alert ("Enter valid number");
   return false;
}
```

you also need to validate that regHours and hourlyRate hold valid numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

your `if` condition

```
if (regHours > 0 || regHours < 80)
```

is **always** true

did you mean

```
if (regHours > 0 && regHours < 80)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and experimenting, and help from the answers I have found a solution to my problem. I figured I'd add it here (this was the complete end result and the part I was having trouble with was the if then for less than 80):

```
    /*global document: false */
/*jslint devel: true */
function calculate() {

    'use strict';

    // Input variables

    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value,

        lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value,

        totHours =
        parseFloat(document.getElementById('totHours').value),

        regHours = parseFloat(document.getElementById('regHours').value),

        overHours = document.getElementById('overHours').value,

        hourlyRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hourlyRate').value),

        fica = document.getElementById('fica').value,

        stateTax = document.getElementById('stateTax').value,

        fedTax = document.getElementById('fedTax').value;





    // Enter in a valid rate
    if ((totHours < 0 || totHours > 80) && (hourlyRate < 0 || hourlyRate > 100.0)) {
        alert("Please enter valid hours and a valid payrate!");
        document.getElementById("theForm").reset("theForm");
    } else if (totHours < 0 || totHours > 80) {
        //return false;
        alert("Please Input valid hours");
        document.getElementById("theForm").reset("theForm");
    } else if (hourlyRate < 0 || hourlyRate > 100.0) {
        alert("Please Input valid hourly rate");
        document.getElementById("theForm").reset("theForm");
    } else {
        //valid
    }
    // For calculations
    if (totHours > 40) {
        overHours = 0;
        overHours += (totHours - 40);
        regHours = 40;
    } else if (totHours <= 40) {
        regHours = totHours;
    }
    document.getElementById('regHours').value = regHours;
    document.getElementById('overHours').value = overHours;

    if (totHours <= 40) {
        document.getElementById('regHours').value = regHours;
    }

    var regPay = (hourlyRate * regHours).toFixed(2),

        overtimePay = (overHours * (1.5 * hourlyRate)).toFixed(2),

        grossPay = parseFloat(+regPay + +overtimePay).toFixed(2),

        totalTax = (parseFloat(+fica + +stateTax + +fedTax) / 100 * grossPay).toFixed(2),

        netPay = (grossPay - totalTax).toFixed(2),

        employeeName = firstName + " " + lastName;

    // output values

    document.getElementById('regPay').value = regPay;

    document.getElementById('overtimePay').value = overtimePay;

    document.getElementById('grossPay').value = grossPay;

    document.getElementById('totalTax').value = totalTax;

    document.getElementById('employeeName').value = employeeName;

    document.getElementById('netPay').value = netPay;


    return false;

}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}

window.onload = init;
```